# Auto Refresh DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My requirement is to auto refresh a DIV every 5 seconds

The DIV content I want to refresh is

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class ="span2">
        <label><spring:message code='total.registration' />:</label>
    </div>
    <div class = "span3">
        ${registrationStatusForm.totalRegis}
    </div>
</div>
```

I also checked some questions on stackoverflow but didn't understand.
Please note that I'm using Spring Web MVC.
Please suggest.

Comment: take a look at setInterval()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new view and controller with minimum elements required to be refreshed.

I also faced the same problem and I fixed it by writing a new controller and a view for the div to be refreshed and then used setInterval, actually setTimeout worked better for my requirement. :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#your_div').load('newController');
}, time_interval);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a jquery question not a spring question since the refresh will be managed on the client.

In jquery, something like this would be appropriate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); 
}); 

function refreshDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://path.to.your/webservice",
        //other stuff you need to build your ajax request
    }).done(function() {
        //update your div
    });
}
```

Comment: Supposed I want to refrsh the DIV result from registration.jsp page then , please let me know if I can use the url as registration.jsp which has the div code to display 
function totalRegisRefresh() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'registration.jsp',
            success : function(data) {
                $('#result').jsp(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var intervalId = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(totalRegisRefresh, 5000);
</script>

Comment: does that jsp page return a full dom or a dom fragment?

Comment: then no.  you're updating a dom fragment not the whole dom.  the best way to do it would be to modify your severside code for this specific piece to return the model or a dom fragment.

Comment: Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Im looking at one example from 
http://crunchify.com/how-to-use-ajax-jquery-in-spring-web-mvc-jsp-example/
Now here in Ajax call URL passed is ajaxtest.html
I didnt get that , wherein the page is ajax.jsp 
Does it mean that I need to write ajax.html another page to display the result ?

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
//code here to refresh div
//possibly: document.getElementById("idOfDiv").innerHTML = "new content";
}, 5000);
```